# Consolidation of two data rows in a loop for n occurrences

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We are running a table that holds some information for order of new products.

From time to time we receive new orders from a 3rd party system and insert them into our DB.

Sometimes, however, for a specific order there is already an entry in our table.

So instead of checking if there already IS an order, the colleagues just inserts new data sets into our table.

Now that the process of inserting is streamlined, I am supposed to consolidate the existing duplicates in the table.

The table looks like this:

[image]

I have 138 of these pairs where the `PreOrderNumber` occurrs twice. I'd like to insert the `FK_VehicleFile` number and the `CommissionNumber` to the row where the `FK_Checklist` is set and delete the duplicate with the missing `FK_Checklist` after that.

My idea is to write a transact script that looks like this:

First I store all the `PreOrderNumbers` that have duplicates in its an own table:

```
DECLARE @ResultSet TABLE (  PK_OrderNumber int, 
                FK_Checklist int, 
                FK_VehicleFile int, 
                PreOrderNumbers varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @ResultSet 
    SELECT  PK_OrderNumber, PreOrderNumber
    FROM [LUX_WEB_SAM].[dbo].[OrderNumbers]
    GROUP BY PreOrderNumber
    HAVING (COUNT(PreOrderNumber) > 1)
```

And that's it so far.

I'm very new to these kind of SQL scripts.

I think I need to use some kind of loop over all entries in the `@ResultSet` table to grab the `FK_VehicleFile` and `CommissionNumber` from the first data set and store them in the second data set.

Or do you have and suggestions how to solve this problem in a more easy way?

Comment: Do you intend to maintain the PK_OrderNumber on this table, or would you like to move your results to another table? This would inform a good response.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide us with some sample data and expected results?

Comment: The data is always the same. I have 138 x 2 data rows that look exactly like the two in the picture above:

The first row has the FK_VehicleFile, PreOrderNumber and CommissionNumber, while the second row has the FK_Checklist. I'd like to merge the first rows information (actually only FK_VehicleFile and CommissionNumber) into the second row where the FK_Checklist number is set.

I have to keep the entries with the FK_Checklist alive and in that table, because these data sets are used in our application.

Comment: Ok, but what about expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This response uses a CTE:

```
WITH [MergedOrders] AS
(
    Select 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY row1.PreOrderNumber ORDER BY row1.PK_OrderNumber) AS Instance
      ,row1.PK_OrderNumber AS PK_OrderNumber
      ,ISNULL(row1.FK_Checklist,row2.FK_Checklist) AS FK_Checklist
      ,ISNULL(row1.FK_VehicleFile,row2.FK_VehicleFile) AS FK_VehicleFile
      ,ISNULL(row1.PreOrderNumber,row2.PreOrderNumber) AS PreOrderNumber
      ,ISNULL(row1.CommissionNumber,row2.CommissionNumber) AS CommissionNumber
    FROM [LUX_WEB_SAM].[dbo].[OrderNumbers] AS row1
    INNER JOIN [LUX_WEB_SAM].[dbo].[OrderNumbers] AS row2
        ON row1.PreOrderNumber = row2.PreOrderNumber
        AND row1.PK_OrderNumber <> row2.PK_OrderNumber
)
SELECT 
   [PK_OrderNumber]
  ,[FK_Checklist]
  ,[FK_VehicleFile]
  ,[PreOrderNumber]
  ,[CommissionNumber]
FROM [MergedOrders]
WHERE Instance = 1 /* If we were to maintain Order Number of second instance, use 2 */
```

Here's the explanation:

A **Common Table Expression (CTE)** acts as an in-memory table, which we use to extract all rows that are repeated (NB: The INNER JOIN statement ensures that only rows that occur twice are selected). We use `ISNULL` to switch out values where one or the other is `NULL`, then select the output for our destination table.

Comment: Even though I do not understand every segment of the script, it seems to generate the correct output. Now I only have to iterate over every row of the table and update my original table with the data of that row. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from following scripts to perform your UPDATE and DELETE action.

> Please keep in mind that both UPDATE and DELETE are risky operation and do your test first with test data.

```
CREATE TABLE #T(
    Col1 VARCHAR(100),
    Col2 VARCHAR(100),
    Col3 VARCHAR(100),
    Col4 VARCHAR(100),
    Col5 VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #T(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)
VALUES(30,NULL,222,00000002222,096),
(25,163,NULL,00000002222,NULL),
(30,163,NULL,00000002230,NULL)

SELECT * FROM #T

UPDATE  A
SET A.Col3 = B.Col3, A.Col5 = B.Col5
FROM #T A
INNER JOIN #T B ON A.Col4 = B.Col4 
WHERE A.Col2 IS NOT NULL AND B.Col2 IS NULL

DELETE FROM #T
WHERE Col4 IN (
    SELECT Col4 FROM #T
    GROUP BY Col4
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
AND Col2 IS NULL

SELECT * FROM #T
```